# How to check instance of key which is present inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have object as,

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    username: 'xyz',
    picture: {
      value: "",
      id: "",
    },
  },
};
```

here keys of **picture** object is dynamic(means picture object do not have same keys always), which change every time. I just want to check whether **obj** have any instance of **Date**. How I can check the whether **obj** have any instance of Date  in js?

Comment: use `obj.a.picture.date` to check the value ?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: use `Object.keys(obj.a.picture)` this will give you array containing all the keys in picture object. then use them to check date instance

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the key is not undefined this way:

```
if(obj.a.picture.date){...code if 'date' exists} else {...code if 'date' not exists}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
  {obj.a?.picture &&
     Object.keys(obj.a.picture).findIndex(key => key === 'Date') > -1 
      ? obj.a.picture["Date"]
      : null
    }
```